# scalatags JsDom vs Text

Tags: html, scala, scalatags

What are differences and purposes of  `scalatags.Text.all._` and `scalatags.JsDom.all._` packages?

In [official scalatags tutorial](http://www.lihaoyi.com/scalatags/#ScalaTags) you can read:

```
// import scalatags.Text.all._
// OR
// import scalatags.JsDom.all._
html(
  head(
    script(src:="..."),
    script(
      "alert('Hello World')"
    )
  ),
  body(
    div(
      h1(id:="title", "This is a title"),
      p("This is a big paragraph of text")
    )
  )
)
And turns them into HTML like this:

<html>
    <head>
        <script src="..."></script>
        <script>alert('Hello World')</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1 id="title">This is a title</h1>
            <p>This is a big paragraph of text</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Differences are described in scalatags documentation in parts [DOMBackend](http://www.lihaoyi.com/scalatags/#DOMBackend) and [Internals](http://www.lihaoyi.com/scalatags/#Internals).

In shortucts when using `scalatags.Text` package, the structure renders directly to `String` but when using `scalatags.JsDOM` package, the structure renders to subtype of `org.scalajs.dom.raw.Element` (which is outside of *scalatags* - it's part of *scalajs* library). When dealing with `Element`s it's possible to further [manipulate dom structure very low level of abstraction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element).

Here, when using `scalatags.Text.`, `h1` renders to `String`:

```
    import scalatags.Text.all._
    val x: String = h1("some header").render
    //x is a String
```

But here, when using `scalatags.JsDom`, `h1` renders to `org.scalajs.dom.raw.HTMLHeadingElement`:

```
    import scalatags.JsDom.all._

    val x: Heading = h1("some header").render
    //x is type of Heading, which is defined as:
    //type Heading = raw.HTMLHeadingElement
    //raw.HTMLHeadingElement is org.scalajs.dom.raw.HTMLHeadingElement
```